# how to change the data type of the second element in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
nested_list = [['bob', '444'], ['steve', '111'], ['mark', '888']]
```

I want to convert the second element in each nested list to the int type. I am trying something like this

```
nested_list2 = []
[int(x[1]) for x in nested_list]
```

this does convert the second element to int, but i lose the rest of the data.

I've also tried this, but it colapses my nested list structure:

```
 [nested_list2.extend((x[0], int(x[1]))) for x in testlist]
```

Is it possible here to end up with something like the following

```
 nested_list2 = [['bob', 444], ['steve', 111], ['mark', 888]]
```

Answer (score 4):

A list comprehension should be used to create a **new** list, not modify an existing list in place:

```
nested_list = [['bob', '444'], ['steve', '111'], ['mark', '888']]

res = [[name, int(num)] for name, num in nested_list]

# [['bob', 444], ['steve', 111], ['mark', 888]]
```

Comment: Interesting .. is the [name, int(num)] a nested list comprehension inside the other list comprehension? Am i reading that correctly?

Comment: @Oscalation, It's actually a list comrpehension of list objects.. `[name, int(num)]` is a regular list.

Answer (score 3):

```
nested_list = [['bob', '444'], ['steve', '111'], ['mark', '888']]
for x in nested_list:
    x[1]=int(x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nested_list2=[]
temp=[]
for i in nested_list:
    for j in i:
        temp.append(j)
    nested_list2.append(temp)
    temp=[]
for i in nested_list2:
    i[1]=int(i[1])
```

Try this and let me know if it is what you needed. Cheers!